# Spring MVC - Tomcat GlobalNamingRessource - Datasource NameNotFoundException

Tags: spring-mvc, jndi, tomcat8

I have read many thread about this issue but couldn't manage to fix it yet. I have this error

`Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dbName] not bound to this context`

I have tomcat 8.5 server.xml :

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource auth="Container"       
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
              name="UserDatabase" 
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />

    <Resource auth="Container" 
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="5" 
              maxWait="-1" 
              name="jdbc/dbName" 
              password="12345" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"        
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1234))    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1234))    (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ABCDEF)    (FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC))))" 
              username="abcdef" />
```

I have `main.java.DataConfig` class in a first application called "framework" :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan("main.java.mapper")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    /**
     * dataSource
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndi = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return jndi.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/dbName");
    }
    ...
```

I pack this application as a war and set it as an overlay for another application. Thus, I have in this application a META-INF/context.xml file like this :

```
<Context>
   <ResourceLink    global="jdbc/dbName"
                    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                    name="jdbc/dbName" />
</Context>
```

The application is building fine with Maven and required dependency are well packed in the war, however, the application cannot find the `GlobalNamingResource` "dbName".

Now if I put the `GlobalNamingResource` in context.xml in Tomcat the datasource is found and everything works fine.

But I don't want to (and cannot) change the context.xml of the server so I want to fetch the datasource and let it as it is in server.xml. How to succeed to do so?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below setting, It work ok in my current project.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/dbName" />
    </bean>
```